# @media inside @media & bad SASS parsing

Tags: css

I have the following sass:

```
.branded
  @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    @media screen and (orientation:portrait)
      background-image: url("../img/fbc/citroen_640x960.jpg")
    @media screen and (orientation:landscape)
      background-image: url("../img/fbc/citroen_960x640.jpg")
    background-size: 50%
```

and it is parsed into the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .branded {
        background-size: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .branded {
        background-image: url("../img/fbc/citroen_640x960.jpg");
    }
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .branded {
        background-image: url("../img/fbc/citroen_960x640.jpg");
    }
}
```

I see it isn't working, and I get an error on this line:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and screen and (orientation:landscape) {
```

Why is it, and how come the SASS parser creates CSS with errors? Is it my mistake or SASSes?

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think it's possible to mix `@media` in standard CSS but [nesting in SASS](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media) is possible.

I may be wrong but I think the errors may be coming from mixing: @media `only screen` and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), `only screen` and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and `screen` and (orientation:landscape)

Try this?

```
.branded
  @media only screen
    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      background-size: 50%
      @media (orientation:portrait)
        background: url("../img/fbc/citroen_640x960.jpg")
      @media (orientation:landscape)
        background: url("../img/fbc/citroen_960x640.jpg")
```